# Not able to refresh the permalink for sharing the Jupyter Notebook on Watson Studio. Any fixes?

Tags: websphere, watson-studio

I tried saving again, making changes to the notebook. I also restarted the kernel and executed all cells again. The share option still shows the same permalink of a previous notebook. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The permalink to shared notebooks never changes. It always points to the last "saved version" of the notebook. What you need to do is publish a new version.

While editing the notebook, select File > Save Version.

Saving a version is different from just saving. You wouldn't want to share each intermediate draft of your notebook, right? It might have been auto-saved while you were in the middle of typing.
So you can edit and save and test as much as you need. Then, when you have completed a better version that you want to share, do the Save Version thing. Afterwards, the permalink points to your new version.